# API jQuery.get seems simple but I can't get it

Tags: jquery, api, get, dogecoin-api

Very new to API, and I'm sure I'm not doing this right - I know because it's not working! I just want to use jQuery's get to pull that simple API and spit it out. This is my first dabble in API. I read the documentation but I'm obviously not understanding it right. Thanks for any assitance.

```
$.get("http://dogechain.info/chain/Dogecoin/q/addressbalance/DT4FWFTjrAA4AvFtkPbVJK3ApYtPHcNnC8", function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: that url displays "500" only when opened, do you get "500" when you do alert(data)?

Comment: Testing it in jsfiddle and I get nothing - not even the alert

Comment: It wont work in fiddle because of `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`

Comment: Open your console(F12). Do you see any red text related to this get request?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://jobs.jsfiddle.net/random.js?callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_0
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Load jquery library and then try it.

Comment: Aditya, looks like you were right "Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. "

How else can I test these GET commands?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://dogechain.info/chain/Dogecoin/q/addressbalance/DT4FWFTjrAA4AvFtkPbVJK3ApYtPHcNnC8') + '&callback=?', function(data){
    alert(data.contents + ' doges');
});
```

The problem is the same-origin policy, which doesn't allow you to load content from other domains.This method uses http://whateverorigin.org to get the info.

To the moon!